Why (and how) is copying prevented on this website?
Apologies for a possibly trivial question, but does anyone know why/how selecting text with the mouse and copying it is disabled on my website: bit.ly/3QzwBwJ. This is hand-coded in PHP and in all the browsers I have tested it in, it is impossible to select and copy the text. I know some people WANT to prevent people copying their text, which seems a bit silly as if someone wants to they will copy anything on the internet, but this wasn't my intention, and I can't see why it is behaving like this. As far as I know, perfectly ordinary HTML is being generated with nothing "clever" to stop copying so I'm puzzled... Can anyone see what's going on?!

I don't think so. That is to do with Javascript setting onContextMenu to preventDefault. I have preventDefault at various places in my scripts, but no mention of onContectMenu.

I think in this case they just set the selection colors the same as the normal text colors. See: ::selection.

@westernKid Follow the duplicate in duplicate to see CSS solutions as well.

Well blow me down, KIKO Software - you've got it! It does copy as normal but you just can't see it. I'll use ::selection to change the selected text colour!

@KIKO-Software's answer is right - it was simply that the colour of selected text was the same as for normal text. I used
body {
   ::selection {
       color: black;
       background: white;
   }
}

to change that and now it's all OK. Simples!

No idea why that was downvoted - that was the answer and it solved the problem. Nothing to do with Javascript or disabling the context menu.

User that have been here for a long time tend to downvote simple answers like this because the answer already exists. They have a vested interest in getting votes on their existing answers, or they have a misplaced sense of duty for maintaining the quality of Stack Overflow. Of course they don't think it is misplaced...  Anyway, it's the reason I don't answer question very often anymore, there's no point.
